# Requesting Advice with parallel programming and webrequest

Tags: multithreading

Currently I have about 20 websites in a list box on my windows form that contain url's.

Each url will navigate to the website download a picture and place the picture into a picture box on the windows form

I have setup 4 picture boxes for the pictures to be entered into.

The user will see the picture of an animal and then will type in the picture and hit a submit button to send the result back to the website for confirmation.

My problem is that when I do try to implement a thread pool I don't have enough time to enter the name of the animal before the next picture loads.

Would it be better for me to create each thread manually and then toggle the button that submits the picture to the site to destroy the thread and grab the next one? I'm very confused. Any help would be awesome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use workers to do your background stuff, and a setinterval hack to simulate threads.

start throwing events, and move up the thread ladder when the event signifying completion is thrown.

Comment: Sweet!! That's exactly I'm going to do.  thanks for the help..do you have any advise on where I can get a guide on that setinterval hack do you?

Comment: Google on simulating threads in javascript. there are several guides. basically you have an array of functions that get executed every x time in a row. the setinterval function checks if the current function has completed. if so, continue to next function, if not wait for next interval round. then throw events if there is something to report. use short event driven pieces of code that take short time to execute like matrix transformations etc. personally i prefer worker because they are true threads(death tio msie for not supporting them yet)

Comment: Oh sorry guys I should of mentioned that I'm using VB.NET. Will the methods that you gave me still apply to vb.net? thanks

Comment: Erm... dont know... i would use js... dont know about threading with vb.net. i’m allergic to micro$ofts programming standards. sorry that i can’t help you then.